# Cannot store values of different tables in a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my sponsor model

```
public enum PaymentType
{
    Cash,
    CreditCard,
    Cheque
}
public class SponsorDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Orphan Orphan { get; set; }
    public int OrphanId  { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public PaymentType PaymentType{ get; set; }
    public int PaymentNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfReceipt { get; set; }
}
```

This is orphan model

```
   public class Orphan
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public bool Disable { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LeaveDate { get; set; }
        public Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }
        public string SupervisorName { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }


    }
```

this is orphan controller

```
public class OrphanController : DatabaseController
    {

            public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Orphans.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Orphan orphan = db.Orphans.Find(id);
            if (orphan == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(orphan);
        }
        public ActionResult Sponsor(int? id )
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            if (Session["UserId"] != null)
            {
                ViewBag.OrphanId = id;
                ViewBag.UserId = Session["UserId"];
            }                 
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Sponsor(SponsorDetail sponsor,int? id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)

            {
                ViewBag.OrphanId = id;
                ViewBag.UserId = Session["UserId"];
                db.SponsorDetails.Add(new SponsorDetail()
                {
                    OrphanId =(int) ViewBag.OrphanId,
                    UserId=(int)ViewBag.UserId,
                    PaymentType = sponsor.PaymentType,
                    PaymentNo  =sponsor.PaymentNo,
                    DateOfReceipt = DateTime.Now

                });
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.OrphanId = new SelectList(db.Orphans, "Id", "FirstName",sponsor.OrphanId);
            return View(sponsor);
        }
    }
```

I have added a sponsor button in my index view of orphan

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Sponsor", "Sponsor",new { id= item.Id })
```

The view of Sponsor for the userid and orphanid

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrphanId, "OrphanId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("OrphanId", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrphanId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "UserId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Editor("UserId", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

After clicking sponsor button it moves to sponsor action of Orphan controller.Since the orphan id is obtained from the value passed from Index view and the userid is obtained from the session.It shows during the Get method of orphan but in post action of sponsor it doesnt store the value in database.Help me how can i store it in database?

Comment: are you getting any exception? is it posting back to the server?

Comment: Disabled controls do not post back a value.

Comment: And in anycase, you cannot read values from `ViewBag` in a POST method - that is only for passing values from a controller to a view.

Comment: An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
 this is  the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made these changes and it worked thank you all for helping me out.

```
 public ActionResult Sponsor(int? id )
            {
                if (Session["UserId"] != null)
                {
                    if (id == null)
                    {
                        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                    }
                    else
                    {                    
                            ViewBag.OrphanId = id;
                            ViewBag.UserId = Session["UserId"];
                    }
                }               
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
                }            
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Sponsor(SponsorDetail sponsor,int? id)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.SponsorDetails.Add(new SponsorDetail()
                    {
                        OrphanId = sponsor.OrphanId,
                        UserId=sponsor.UserId,
                        PaymentType = sponsor.PaymentType,
                        PaymentNo  =sponsor.PaymentNo,
                        DateOfReceipt = DateTime.Now

                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ViewBag.Message = "Successful";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                ViewBag.OrphanId = new SelectList(db.Orphans, "Id", "FirstName",sponsor.OrphanId);
                return View(sponsor);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid reading values from ViewBag in controller. ViewBag is just a collection of data that can be exchanged between controller and view. Your sponsor method should be then like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Sponsor(SponsorDetail sponsor,int? id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)

            {
                ViewBag.OrphanId = id;
                ViewBag.UserId = Session["UserId"];
                db.SponsorDetails.Add(new SponsorDetail()
                {
                    OrphanId =(int)id,
                    UserId= Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]),
                    PaymentType = sponsor.PaymentType,
                    PaymentNo  =sponsor.PaymentNo,
                    DateOfReceipt = DateTime.Now

                });
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.OrphanId = new SelectList(db.Orphans, "Id", "FirstName",sponsor.OrphanId);
            return View(sponsor);
        }
```

Moreover, you are not returning any sponsor to the view. How you will manage your model if you are not returning it.
I would use like this:

```
    public ActionResult Sponsor(int? id )
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                if (Session["UserId"] != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.OrphanId = id;
                    ViewBag.UserId = Session["UserId"]; 
                    //you need to fill the sponsorModel here an return it back in the view
                }                 
                return View(sponsorModel);
            }
```